Combine likert plot from appended data frame and bar plot from pure data frame in R using ggplot2
I have a data frame in R called df :
library(tibble)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstats)

var_levels <- c(LETTERS[1:20])
n = 500
likert_levels = c(
  "Very \n Dissatisfied",
  "Dissatisfied",
  "Neutral",
  "Satisfied",
  "Very \n Satisfied"
)

df <- tibble(
  var = sample(var_levels, n, replace = TRUE),  
  val1 = sample(likert_levels, n, replace = TRUE), 
  val2 = sample(likert_levels, n, replace = TRUE) ,
  val3 = sample(likert_levels, n, replace = TRUE) 
)

This data frame contains the correct count of var levels A, B and C.
Then I append each category-question with pivot longer in R :
df2 = df%>%
  pivot_longer(!var, names_to = "Categories", values_to = "likert_values")%>%
  select(-Categories)


resulting to :
 var   likert_values         
   <chr> <chr>                 
 1 B     "Very \n Satisfied"   
 2 B     "Dissatisfied"        
 3 B     "Dissatisfied"        
 4 B     "Dissatisfied"        
 5 B     "Very \n Dissatisfied"
 6 B     "Very \n Dissatisfied"
 7 A     "Dissatisfied"        
 8 A     "Dissatisfied"        
 9 A     "Neutral"             
10 C     "Very \n Dissatisfied"
# ℹ 140 more rows


I want to create two plots.One with ggplikert or ggplot2 that will create facets on the likert chart based on the levels of the var column and to be sorted based on the two lower likert levels (ie "Very \n Dissatisfied" and "Dissatisfied") and keep the first 10 levels (ie the most dissatisfied levels). The second plot I want to be a bar plot but this df2 data frame with pivot longer cannot be used for the count due to the pivot longer. I have to use the first data frame df.But I want to match horizontally the levels on the likert chart and the bar plot.How can I do it in R ?

@stefan can you have a go on this one ?

This is a modification of the approach I used in this answer, i.e. I use same code for the likert plot and use patchwork to add corresponding bar charts of counts:
library(tidyverse)
library(ggstats)

set.seed(123)


dat <- df |>
  mutate(
    across(-var, ~ factor(.x, likert_levels))
  ) |>
  pivot_longer(-var, names_to = "group") |>
  count(var, value, group) |>
  complete(var, value, group, fill = list(n = 0)) |>
  mutate(
    prop = n / sum(n),
    prop_lower = sum(prop[value %in% likert_levels[1:2]]),
    prop_higher = sum(prop[value %in% likert_levels[4:5]]),
    .by = c(var, group)
  ) |>
  arrange(group, prop_lower) |>
  mutate(
    y_sort = paste(var, group, sep = "."),
    y_sort = fct_inorder(y_sort)
  )

top10 <- dat |>
  distinct(group, var, prop_lower) |>
  slice_max(prop_lower, n = 10, by = group)

dat <- dat |>
  semi_join(top10)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(var, group, prop_lower)`

dat_tot <- dat |>
  distinct(group, var, y_sort, prop_lower, prop_higher) |>
  pivot_longer(-c(group, var, y_sort),
    names_to = c(".value", "name"),
    names_sep = "_"
  ) |>
  mutate(
    hjust_tot = ifelse(name == "lower", 1, 0),
    x_tot = ifelse(name == "lower", -1, 1)
  )

dat_bar <- dat |> 
  summarise(
    n = sum(n), .by = c(y_sort, group)
  )

p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(y = y_sort, x = prop, fill = value)) +
  geom_col(position = position_likert(reverse = FALSE)) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      label = label_percent_abs(hide_below = .05, accuracy = 1)(prop),
      color = after_scale(hex_bw(.data$fill))
    ),
    position = position_likert(vjust = 0.5, reverse = FALSE),
    size = 3.5
  ) +
  geom_label(
    aes(
      x = x_tot,
      label = label_percent_abs(accuracy = 1)(prop),
      hjust = hjust_tot,
      fill = NULL
    ),
    data = dat_tot,
    size = 3.5,
    color = "black",
    fontface = "bold",
    label.size = 0,
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = \(x) gsub("\\..*$", "", x)) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = label_percent_abs(),
    expand = c(0, .15)
  ) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "BrBG") +
  facet_wrap(~group,
    scales = "free_y", ncol = 1,
    strip.position = "right"
  ) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    strip.text = element_blank()
  ) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL)

p2 <- ggplot(dat_bar, aes(y = y_sort, x = n)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_label(
    aes(
      label = label_number_abs(hide_below = .05, accuracy = 1)(n)
    ),
    size = 3.5,
    hjust = 1,
    fill = NA,
    label.size = 0,
    color = "white"
  ) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = \(x) gsub("\\..*$", "", x)) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = label_number_abs(),
    expand = c(0, 0, 0, .05)
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~group,
             scales = "free_y", ncol = 1,
             strip.position = "right"
  ) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()
  ) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL)

library(patchwork)

p1 + p2 +
  plot_layout(
    #axes = "collect", 
    guides = "collect") &
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")



in the likert plots , why there is so much empty white space between the bars and the totals at right and left ? Can you diminish the white space ?

dat_bar in wrong.the bar count on the bar plot are not the the original df but of the appended daata frame.So is wrong.

Could you clarify what's wrong with the counts? Whether I compute the counts for the original df or the aggregated df does not matter, e.g. run df |>    count(var) and you will get the same counts as shown in the bar plots. But perhaps I misunderstand what counts you want to display in the barchart.

you are correct I am sorry

Concerning your first question. I positioned the labels at +/-100% which is done in the code line x_tot = ifelse(name == "lower", -1, 1). Hence, you can reduce the value to e.g. +/- .8 to place it at 80%.

Regarding the sorting matching I wanted to ask the following:The val1 val 2 and and val3 and being appended on df2.This df2 must be used for the likert plot.But since it is the df but appended it is not accurate to bar count the levels of var in df2.I have to do the bar count on df.So the likert chart will have the data from df2 but the bar plot will be from df.That was my intention.Sorry for the misunderstanding I didn’t communicate it properly

I made a more clear question regarding the append data frame and the pure here

[updated answer] You can do it like this:
library(tibble)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstats)

# Define variables
var_levels <- c(LETTERS[1:20])
n <- 500
likert_levels <- c(
  "Very \n Dissatisfied",
  "Dissatisfied",
  "Neutral",
  "Satisfied",
  "Very \n Satisfied"
)

# Generate the data
df <- tibble(
  var = sample(var_levels, n, replace = TRUE),
  val1 = sample(likert_levels, n, replace = TRUE),
  val2 = sample(likert_levels, n, replace = TRUE),
  val3 = sample(likert_levels, n, replace = TRUE)
)

# Pivot longer for Likert chart
df2 <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(!var, names_to = "Categories", values_to = "likert_values") %>%
  select(-Categories)

# Aggregate data for the Likert plot
likert_summary <- df2 %>%
  group_by(var, likert_values) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
  mutate(likert_values = factor(likert_values, levels = likert_levels)) %>%
  group_by(var) %>%
  mutate(prop = count / sum(count)) %>%
  ungroup()

# Sort 'var' levels by the total dissatisfaction (first 2 levels)
dissatisfaction_order <- likert_summary %>%
  filter(likert_values %in% c("Very \n Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied")) %>%
  group_by(var) %>%
  summarise(total_dissatisfied = sum(prop), .groups = "drop") %>%
  arrange(desc(total_dissatisfied)) %>%
  slice_head(n = 10) %>%
  pull(var)

likert_summary <- likert_summary %>%
  filter(var %in% dissatisfaction_order) %>%
  mutate(var = factor(var, levels = dissatisfaction_order))

# Prepare data for the bar plot
bar_data <- df %>%
  count(var) %>%
  filter(var %in% dissatisfaction_order) %>%
  mutate(var = factor(var, levels = dissatisfaction_order))

# Plot 1: Likert Chart
likert_plot <- ggplot(likert_summary, aes(x = likert_values, y = prop, fill = likert_values)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack") +
  facet_wrap(~ var, ncol = 10, scales = "fixed", strip.position = "bottom") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn", name = "Likert Levels") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    axis.text.x = element_blank()  # Remove x-axis labels
  ) +
  labs(title = "Likert Chart by Var Levels",
       x = "Likert Levels",
       y = "Proportion")


# Plot 2: Bar Plot
bar_plot <- ggplot(bar_data, aes(x = var, y = n, fill = var)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Counts of Var Levels",
       x = "Var Levels",
       y = "Count")

library(patchwork)
# Combine the plots horizontally
combined_plot <- bar_plot  + likert_plot  + plot_layout(ncol = 2)

# Print the combined plot
print(combined_plot)

and it will look like this:


Both of them must be horizontal and matching the levels of the two plots

@HomerJaySimpson Hey Homer, can you please eleborate on what you mean with
"But I want to match horizontally the levels on the likert chart and the bar plot.How can I do it in R ?"
Do you want (A) that the bars of both charts to horizontally align so that they grow out of the same x-axis? Or (B) do you want that and also that both y-axis scales align (proportion and count)?

the A) option which is what i want.But if you flip both plots on yours solution it will give the desired result

@HomerJaySimpson I flipped the plots.
